# Applying Calibration Function - Existing PMML

Tags: lightgbm, pmml, sigmoid

I have a PMML for a LGBM (python API) model but would like to apply a calibration function to the predictions. An example of a calibration function would be sigmoid or isotonic regression. Not sure on how to add this to the existing PMML.

Answer (score 1):

Details here on how to make is possible https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn/issues/146